# zindex in LongListSelector

Tags: windows-phone, z-index, longlistselector

The question I have has been asked before here [How to set the the zindex of datatemplate's in a longlistselector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151071/how-to-set-the-the-zindex-of-datatemplates-in-a-longlistselector) earlier, but never got any answer.  So I'm asking it myself, hoping someone can help me.

I have a `LongListSelector`. The `ItemTemplate` consists of a `Border`. Now trying to do something like drag and drop i made it possible to move objects (an element (Border) in the longListSelector) in vertical direction. if i move to the top, everything is fine, if I move to the bottom, the element i'm moving passes behind the other elements of the `LongListSelector`. So my first guess was to set the zIndex by `Canvas.SetZIndex(border, 1);`

But it does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps if you [asked a better question...](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sry to bother, but the original thread has no answer, I wouldn't have asked otherwise.

Comment: @robertharvey I believe your "close as duplicate" is incorrect.  While the linked question may or may not be the same question, the second clause (and already has an answer) does not hold.  The other question is not answered.  Other close reasons may be valid.